# Is it possible to programmatically add elements to a controller tag? (LogixDesigner Studio 5000)

Tags: plc

I have a program with a scanner connected to a PLC for part inputs. There are two options:

1. Manually input the data (size, color, oven time, part number)
2. Scan the part ticket to input the data (size, color, oven time, part number)

Right now I have a controller tag labeled "part_number" which has 130 elements (20 are empty), each of which contain the 4 pieces of information as a String, Dint, Dint and String respectively.

This is great for when we scan a part ticket, the program looks up the number and auto loads the recipe parameters. However, we make new parts every day, so if they scan the ticket and no part is found a message box opens on the HMI and asks them to manually input the data. If we create more than 20 parts then either I will have to manually create the element to represent this new part number.

I was hoping there would be a way to detect when a part number is not found, display the message, save the information as Part_number[n+1].

I haven't been able to find information about this online, it online brings up videos about how to create tags (not helpful in my case).

As of yet I haven't tired anything because I do not even know where to begin. I am self taught so I don't have a very in depth knowledge about the capabilities of Studio 5000.

Comment: It kinda sounds like you're hoping to increase the size of an array during runtime? If that's the case then, no, that's not possible.

Comment: Do you have access to the PLC source code? Is it possible to show the declaration of the variable "part_number"?